# How to generate a list of available updates from yum and export to CSV, including current and updated version of each package?

Tags: linux, bash, centos7, rpm

I am running the following script on a Centos 7 box.  The idea is to list packages that are currently available to update, along with the current version and new version.  Once I get this accomplished, I will then send the results to a .csv file to import into excel.

Here is the bash script I am using:

```
#! /usr/bin/bash

echo \"timestamp\",\"package name\",\"current version\",\"update version\"
yum -q check-update| while read i
do
    i=$(echo $i) #this strips off yum's irritating use of whitespace
    if [ "${i}x" != "x" ]
    then
        TIMESTAMP=$( date +%D" "%r )
        UVERSION=${i#*\ }
        UVERSION=${UVERSION%\ *}
        PNAME=${i%%\ *}
        PNAME=${PNAME%.*}
        echo \"$TIMESTAMP\",$(rpm -q "${PNAME}" --qf '"%{NAME}","%{VERSION}","')${UVERSION}\"
    fi
done
```

This is what the results look like:

> "timestamp","package name","current version","update version"
>   "06/20/18 02:19:37 PM","cloudbackup-updater","1.5.3","1.5.16-1" 
>   "06/20/18 02:19:37 PM","dhclient","4.1.1","12:4.1.1-53.P1.el6.centos.4" 
>   "06/20/18 02:19:37 PM","dhcp-common","4.1.1","12:4.1.1-53.P1.el6.centos.4" 
>   "06/20/18 02:19:37 PM","kernel","2.6.32",""kernel","2.6.32",""kernel","2.6.32",""kernel","2.6.32",""kernel","2.6.32","2.6.32-696.30.1.el6" 
>   "06/20/18 02:19:37 PM","kernel-firmware","2.6.32","2.6.32-696.30.1.el6"
>   "06/20/18 02:19:37 PM","kernel-headers","2.6.32","2.6.32-696.30.1.el6"

Notice the 5th line is repeating information.  I think this is because the script is querying for the package "kernel" instead of the full name "kernel.x86_64" when it does the RPM query.

If I run

```
yum check-update
```

The following packages are available to update:

> cloudbackup-updater.noarch 
>   dhclient.x86_64 
>  dhcp-common.x86_64 
>  kernel.x86_64 
>  kernel-firmware.noarch 
> kernel-headers.x86_64

What is wrong with my script, causing it to match only the first part of the name for each package instead of the full name?

Comment: FYI, `yum` has a nice native-Python interface that you might find useful instead of trying to parse text that could change in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is the `PNAME` assignment

```
PNAME=${PNAME%.*}
```

This is something I have used to remove extensions from filenames.  You are removing everything (and including) to the right of the period.  Really no need for this line as far as I can see.  Would also be a good idea to quote variable assignments. So something like this:

```
TIMESTAMP="$( date +%D" "%r )"
UVERSION="${i#*\ }"
UVERSION="${UVERSION%\ *}"
PNAME="${i%%\ *}"
#PNAME="${PNAME%.*}"
```

Output of `$PNAME` on these assignments:

```
cloudbackup-updater.noarch
dhclient.x86_64
dhcp-common.x86_64
kernel.x86_64
kernel-firmware.noarch
kernel-headers.x86_64
```

**EDIT**
I am thinking that your while loop is parsing the output of yum incorrectly.  Try changing that line to this:

```
yum -q check-update | tr -s " " | while read PNAME UVERSION extra
```

This should handle yum's space issue so you can remove `i=$(echo $i)`.  Also, this will read the individual values directly into the variables.  Then, since `$i` no longer exists, you can change `if [ "${i}x" != "x" ]` to `if [ "${PNAME}x" != "x" ]` (This is actually a pretty clever way to check for a blank). So the final script should look like this:

```
echo \"timestamp\",\"package name\",\"current version\",\"update version\"
yum -q check-update | tr -s " " | while read PNAME UVERSION extra
do
    if [ "${PNAME}x" != "x" ]; then
        TIMESTAMP=$( date +%D" "%r )
        echo \"$TIMESTAMP\",$(rpm -q "${PNAME}" --qf '"%{NAME}","%{VERSION}","')${UVERSION}\"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thank you! This does indeed fix the variable PNAME to include the full name.  But for some reason rpm is taking that name and finding multiple results. For example if I run `rpm -q kernel.x86_64 --qf "%{NAME}`, the output is `kernelkernelkernelkernelkernel`.  It looks like the problem lies within my rpm database on multiple servers, which show 5 instances of the kernel package.  I upvoted your answer but I have less than 15 reputation so it doesn't change the public display of the answer.

Comment: @James  Check out the edit.  See if that helps at all.  If this fixes your problem, you can click the check next to the answer to accept this as the solution.

Comment: I appreciate the effort but with your updated script, I still get the same results.

Comment: I tried the script out and I'm getting the following type of error: ./_script.sh: line 8: [binutils.x86_64 2.27-41.base.el7 rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releasesx: command not found